# Aligning divs horizontaly inside dragable div in gantt chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to develop a Gantt chart to display a certain list of grouped activities. In the image below I have attached the sample set of data that is used to generate my Gantt chart.[image]

I have used the Gantt chart provided in this link (http://yukon-admin.tzdthemes.com/html/plugins-gantt_chart.html) and modified it so that I can display multiple activities per group. [In here they only let you add one activity per group].

This is the Gantt chart from the template,
[image]

Modified Gantt chart based on my requirement,
[image]

Now I want to display my activities one after the other, something similar to what would happen when you apply float:left,(float:left is not working in this situation).

This is how I want to display my activities, I can achieve this by setting the CSS property to absolute but the lines stay static and I can't scroll my gantt chart to see the other activities. 
[image]

I see that even though a width is defined to that particular div, it is taking up the whole width of its container div.That's why the divs are stacked one below the other.
[image]

What can I do to get the lines displayed one beside the other and not one below the other? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you provide live demo of your code?